# How can i write a query that groups by time in 30 minute periods in BigQuery

Tags: google-bigquery

I am trying to write a query that shows some info and groups all according to 30 minute periods. The time is given in Timestamp

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at [Window functions](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/query-reference#windowfunctions)
Pay special attention to the `RANGE` option for `<window-frame-clause>`

*Your question is quite generic and has no much details and or examples; so I assume you expect/accept same generic answer*